# Recover json data from youtube api call

Tags: javascript, php, api, youtube

I executed the code to retrieve the info from subscriber and all is well but the problem I can't get the info in json format

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
<script>
  /**
   * Sample JavaScript code for youtube.subscriptions.list
   * See instructions for running APIs Explorer code samples locally:
   * https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/guides/code_samples#javascript
   */

  function authenticate() {
    return gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
        .signIn({scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly"})
        .then(function() { console.log("Sign-in successful"); },
              function(err) { console.error("Error signing in", err); });
  }
  function loadClient() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey("AIzxxxxxxxxxxx");
    return gapi.client.load("https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/youtube/v3/rest")
        .then(function() { console.log("GAPI client loaded for API"); },
              function(err) { console.error("Error loading GAPI client for API", err); });
  }
  // Make sure the client is loaded and sign-in is complete before calling this method.
  function execute() {
    return gapi.client.youtube.subscriptions.list({
      "part": [
        "snippet,contentDetails"
      ],
      "forChannelId": "UCASxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "mine": true
    })
        .then(function(response) {
                // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
                console.log("Response", response);
                
                
                ?????????????

              },
              function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
  }
  gapi.load("client:auth2", function() {
    gapi.auth2.init({client_id: "5000000020-au42cxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"});
  });
</script>
```

I looked at the console and I saw that the information is retrieved in response but not in json format

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5t97.jpg)

Comment: What does `console.log("Response", response);` shows? - try use `console.log(response);` instead and see the results in the console.

Comment: Hello
https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5t97.jpg

Comment: The response IS in json format. Clarify how are you trying to read the `response`. Once you have the `response`, then you can access to the results, for example: `response.results`.

Comment: thank you for your help it works

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the response of the API, you need to check its content and get the values you need.

Example:

```
.then(function(response) {
    // This is the response of the API.
    console.log(response);

    // Once you got the response, view its content.
    // For example, if you want get the "results" value 
    // of the "response", use: 
    console.log(response.results);
  },
  function(err) {
    console.error("Execute error", err);
  });
```